# Updating form in own composite-components in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have the following (simplified, but the issue can be demonstrated) component `my:slot`

```
<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="xxx" layout="block">
    <composite:insertChildren/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
```

Now I want to ad forms to use this component with two forms:

```
<my:slot>
    <h:form id="f3">
        <p:commandButton value="update f4" update=":f4"/>  
    </h:form>
</my:slot>
<my:slot>
  <h:form id="f4">Form f4</h:form>
</my:slot>
```

With this code I get the error `Cannot find component with identifier ":f4" referenced from "j_idt11:f3:j_idt12"`. It's ok if I use the `h:form id="f4"` outside of `my:slot`. How can I use `h:form` in own components like shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composite components are by itself also [naming containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) like as `<h:form>`. Look in the generated HTML output. Their IDs are prepended to the ID of the children.

You need to give your composite component a fixed ID so that JSF won't autogenerate an unpredictable one and then reference it in the `update`.

```
<my:slot id="slot1">
    <h:form id="f3">
        <p:commandButton value="update f4" update=":slot2:f4"/>  
    </h:form>
</my:slot>
<my:slot id="slot2">
  <h:form id="f4">Form f4</h:form>
</my:slot>
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)